# React Formik Material UI Autocomplete: how to set value of material ui Autocomplete programmatically using Formik

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, formik

I have two select options, 1st is for a movie and the 2nd one is for a release year of the respective movie. Once I select a movie from the 1st Autocomplete, I need to set the value of the 2nd Autocomplete to release the year of the movie selected in the 1st select box.

Here is codesandbox link for working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-bardeen-eihgv?file=/index.js

[image]

Comment: I got the solution for this and I am using [https://stackworx.github.io/formik-mui/](https://stackworx.github.io/formik-mui/) lib for data bindings, here is the working solution https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-material-ui-autocomplete-rishd?file=/index.js

PS: Please reload sandbox in case of any dependencies error

Comment: If you found the solution you can add an answer to your question instead of a comment.

Comment: @AlaBenAicha I tried to do that but it doesn’t allow me to add answer, might be I don’t have enough points to do that